# Buy Bitcoin with NBitcoin c# Web App

Tags: transactions, wallet, api, c#, nbitcoin

I have been using the NBitcoin lib with c# to create a Bitcoin wallet app. I have pretty much sorted out the creation of the wallet and everything that this entails. What I need some help with is on the MAIN(real-world) network, how to I purchase bitcoin to populate my wallet with. Does this also happen via the library in c#? Does the NBitcoin package allow you to do this?

There is a lot of documentation on setting up the wallets, finding wallets and transacting but very little info on how to fund the bitcoin wallet? If I use Luno as an example, on there you purchase bitcoin by using a credit/debit card and its the bitcoin value is available in your Bitcoin wallet within the Luno app. This is similar what I am trying to achieve. Some guidance on this will be extremely appreciated. I also dont expect easy answers and am willing to work for this one, but some info will really be welcomed.